# How to show different JSP page depending on certain conditions in Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations

I am working on Spring MVC controller project. I have a JSP page which contains certain forms and people will type certain entries in it and then press submit button.

Now below is my code base - As soon as I hit this url on the browser -

```
http://localhost:8080/testweb/testOperation
```

It automatically goes to below method if I put a breakpoint and then it shows me my `testOperation` jsp page on the browser and it works fine.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> testOperation() {
    final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    return model;
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is - suppose in the below method as soon as the call comes, I will extract IP Address from the headers where the call is coming, if the IP Address doesn't matches, then I would like to show error JSP page but if the IP Address matches then I would show `testOperation` jsp page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> testOperation(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

   //is client behind something?
   String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
   if (ipAddress == null) {  
       ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
   }

    if(ipAddress.equals("something_here")) {
        // then load testOperation jsp page
    } else {
        // otherwise load some error jsp page
    }

    return model;
}
```

Is this possible to do somehow?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-return-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in another answer, you can definitely do what you are asking just by returning a different `ModelAndView` (or even just the model name will do), but if are planning to use the IP lookup strategy I would suggest you take a look at Spring MVC's `HandlerInterceptor`.
Take a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) blog post for more details

**EDIT**

Actually I am revising my thinking... I am now suggesting that you should use a HandlerMethodArgumentResolver to inject the a boolean that shows whether or not the user is behind something, into your controller method. The relevant code would be :

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BehindSomething{
}

import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer;
@Component
public class IsBehindSomethingHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(RemoteAddress.class) != null
                && methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(Boolean.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
        final String ipAddress = nativeWebRequest.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
        if (ipAddress == null) {
            ipAddress =(((ServletWebRequest) nativeWebRequest).getRequest()).getRemoteAddr();
        }

        return ipAddress.equals("something_here");
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> testOperation(@BehindSomething Boolean behindSomething) {
       final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

       if(behindSomething) {
           // then load testOperation jsp page
       } else {
           // otherwise load some error jsp page
       }

       return model;
}
```

Also, dependending on how you have setup Spring, you will have to register `IsBehindSomethingHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` (if you need tips on that, let me know)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can you provide an example how would I solve my question basis on the suggestion you gave which is using `Interceptor`? Actually I am slightly new to this so if you can provide an example then it will be of great help.

Comment: I will get back to you in a couple of days with some code, because now I do not have access to my working examples

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. In the `testOperation` method you have `if(behindSomething)` what is this `behindSomething` here?

Comment: It is the value returned by IsBehindSomethingHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument

Comment: Aahh.. Just noticed that.. Can you tell me what is the difference between HandlerInterceptor vs the suggestion you just gave?

Comment: What I am suggesting here allows you to have a boolean (behindSomething) that you can put inside any controller you like. That way you don't need to perform the same checks over and over, just check the boolean

Answer (score 0):

Just return respective pages:

```
if(ipAddress.equals("something_here")) {
        return new ModelAndView("testOperation.jsp");
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("error.jsp");
    }
```